# Backbone sync event bubbling down?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Rails/Backbone app with some nested models; a Shelf has Games, which each have Ratings and Reviews. When I fetch a shelf, it appears to trigger a `sync` event on the Shelf, and parses the request contents properly, but does not appear to trigger `sync` on the Games Collection.

Is this the normal way the sync event behaves, and is there a standard way to pass sync events down the chain to child collections and models?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proper solution, but solved this particular issue by simply issuing `trigger('sync')` on initialize.